# What's the default password in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I install postgres on tutorial [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-12-04), but when I paste `

> sudo su – postgres

bash show me

> [sudo] password for postgres:

and want to know what I do?
what's the password?

sorry for the bad English
`

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That prompt suggests you're probably already the `postgres` system user, so you don't need to `sudo`. Just run the command you're trying to run directly.

---

In general, don't use `sudo su - postgres`. It's pointless. Just:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

or whatever directly. To get a shell:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

There is never any need to use `su -` with `sudo`.